# .swf file gets cut short after conversion to mp3 with ffmpeg

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, swf

So I have a .swf file which i need to convert to .mp3 (or any other audio file), it looks like this:

```
vytautas@vytautas-SATELLITE-C660:~/Desktop$ ffmpeg -i rem.swf
ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 18 2014 02:20:25 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --enable-libpulse --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      52. 84.100 / 52. 84.100
  libavcodec     55. 62.100 / 55. 62.100
  libavformat    55. 38.100 / 55. 38.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
  libavresample   1.  2.  0 /  1.  2.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[swf @ 0x2762ae0] SWF compressed file detected
[swf @ 0x2762ae0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: pcm_u8, 5512 Hz, mono, 44 kb/s): unspecified sample format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, swf, from 'rem.swf':
  Duration: 00:00:00.55, bitrate: 98 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 5512 Hz, mono, 44 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 128 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

So it's length is : 00:00:00.55, but then I convert it to .mp3 using this command:

```
 ffmpeg -i rem.swf -map 0:1 -acodec copy rem.mp3
```

and this is the output I get:

```
**output ommited, as it is same as above**
Input #0, swf, from 'rem.swf':
  Duration: 00:00:00.55, bitrate: 98 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 5512 Hz, mono, 44 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 128 kb/s
File 'rem.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp3, to 'rem.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf55.38.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=       5kB time=00:00:00.33 bitrate= 130.7kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:5kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 9.080189%
```

So now the length is only 00:00:00.33, any ideas?

Here is the link to the file, even if yous could try converting it on your own machine that would help as well:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByJlZbStPk2cS0FwN09TX2VkWjg/edit

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is offtopic: [so] is for programming quesitons only. You can flag a moderator to migrate it to [su] where `ffmpeg` cli questions are on-topic.

Comment: Sorry. I flagged. So I just wrote comment that it should be migrated to super user, is that all I needed to do?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.